# What are the specifics of the relation between CPU usage and power consumption on iOS?

Tags: ios, cpu, battery

I've read through Apple's documentation on CPU power consumption, but I still have some lingering questions.

Does 1% CPU usage have the same amount of overhead to keep the CPU powered on as 100% CPU usage?

Does each core power up and down independently?

How long does it take before the CPU powers down after it starts idling?

Will the system commonly be using the CPU for its own tasks, thus keeping the CPU on regardless?

For my app in particular, I'm finding it hard to get the CPU to 0% for any decent amount of time. In a typical session, there's at least going to be a steady stream of UIScrollView delegate calls and UITableViewCell recycle calls as the user moves around the app, let alone interacts with the content. However, based on this post, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/why-does-gps-on-the-iphone-use-so-much-power, the CPU sounds like a major energy culprit. I'm hoping even a small pause while they use the app would let the CPU save some power, so then I can just work on getting rid of long-running tasks.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably too broad a question to be really answered in this format. All of it "depends" and is subject to change as the OS and hardware change. However, you should start by watching the various [energy-related videos from WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/search/?type=Videos&q=energy) (there are a lot of them).

In principle, the difference between 0% CPU usage and 1% CPU usage is enormous. However, the difference between 1% and 100% is also enormous. The system absolutely does turn on and off different parts of the CPU (including a whole core) depending on how busy it is, and if it can get down to zero for even a few tens of milliseconds periodically, it can dramatically improve battery life (this is why recent versions of iOS allow you to specify timer tolerances, so it can batch work together and then get back to low-power mode).

All that said, you shouldn't expect to be at zero CPU while the user is actually interacting with your app. Obviously responding to the user is going to take work. You should explore your energy usage with Instruments to look for places that are excessive, but I would expect the CPU to be "doing things" while the user is scrolling (how could it not?) You shouldn't try to artificially inject pauses or anything to let the CPU sleep. As a general rule of thumb, it is best to use the CPU fully if it helps you get done faster, and then do nothing. By that I mean, it is much better to parse all of a massive download (as an example) as fast as you can and use 100% CPU, than to spread it out and use 20% CPU for 5x as long.

The CPU is there to be used. You just don't want to waste it.